# Generic solution to deselect buttons in java

Tags: java, swing

In a set of radio buttons of the same group, only one can be selected at the same time. I would like to have the same behaviour with a normal button.

Imagine there's a row of 3 buttons. When a button is selected it changes: but.setSelected(true) and the other two buttons should be NOT selected: but.setSelected(false)

Now, is there a generic, simple and clean solution to accomplish that in Java (Swing) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JButton` extends `AbstractButton` (in the same way `JRadioButton` does) and hence you can use the **same solution** as with `JRadioButton`: Simply add a number of `JButton`s to a [`ButtonGroup`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html).

However, typically this approach will be unintuitive to the end user as people don't generally expect buttons to remain "stuck down"; This is specifically why `JRadioButton`s exist.

Comment: Your right using this with standard JButton will make the users lost, but you can want this behaviour with JToggleButton.

Comment: It's a good point - You should use JToggleButton to ensure that the button remains stuck down.  JRadioButton and JCheckBox are both subclasses of JToggleButton.

Answer (score 1):

The is a special  component for that - [JToggleButton](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html). It is exactly what you want. It can be used with ButtonGroup as radio buttons and check boxes (they are descendants of toggle button)

Comment: +1 In addition, putting `JToggleButton`s in a `ButtonGroup` will produce the required single-selection. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html